# How do I create a class method that adds a key to a global dictionary in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, oop, methods

I am trying to build a database class in python, where i can add tables and rows and run other methods.

I'm facing an issue where when I add a table, it's not getting saved in the global dictionary. My code is as follows;

```
class DataBase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
        
    def addTable(self, tableName):
        self.data[tableName] = {}
```

When I run that, then add a table and call on the dictionary, I still get an empty dict (as below)

```
tableName = "table"
DataBase().addTable(tableName)

DataBase().data

#output
{}
```

Can anyone help explain why this is?

Comment: Looks like you are intentionally adding the table as a part of that object. That's what the "self" does in this case. 
If you want to keep the classes, you could always make your "global" class a super class and your tables a sub class.

Comment: You are creating (and discarding) separate instances of `DataBase` each time. `data` is *not* global; it's an instance attribute.

Comment: For starters, objects are neither global nor local - objects don't have a scope - **variables do**. Second, `self.data` is not global, it is *an instance attribute*. You keep instantiating a new instance every time you call `DataBase()`, so of course, a new instance attribute is created. This is a pretty fundamental concept. What did you expect this to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
tableName = "table"
x = DataBase()
x.addTable(tableName)
```

The problem with your code is that when you did DataBase().addTable(tablename) what python did is initialize a new object because of DataBase() and added a table to it instead of the one you wanted it to add to.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize the class

```
myDataBase = Database()
```

Comment: You initialize *instances*; the OP is doing that, but doing it multiple times instead of using a single instance.